# how to select and count the each individual words from file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, count, rdd, distinct-values

```
hello how are you
I am fine
how are you
I am also fine
Thank you
```

This is the file I have, I want to count how many times each word is repeated on the file? So the output should look like

```
(hello,1)
(how,2)
(are,2)
(you,3)
```

and so on.

I tried this

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path")
val rdd1= rdd.map(x=>(x.distinct,x.length)).collect
```

but it didn't work? Please help.

Comment: hello how are you was the first line, it got deleted when it was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `countByValue()`:

```
rdd.map(x => x.split(" ")).flatMap(x => x).countByValue()
```

which returns a map:

```
Map(are -> 2, am -> 2, I -> 2, you -> 3, also -> 1, how -> 2, Thank -> 1, fine -> 2, hello -> 1)
```

If you want an RDD you can do

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(rdd.map(x => x.split(" ")).flatMap(x => x).countByValue().toSeq)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I added .foreach(prinln) at the end